# Tsql - How to Cast and Convert the same field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this value in a field  +000000019900000000

The actual value that I need is 19.90.

How do I write a statement to convert and cast this all on the same line?

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? Can you share the code you have written?

Comment: How do you come up with 19.90? Why not 1990? Or 1.990?

Comment: I know it's 19.90 because it's a price on a security that I comparing with the front end system.

Comment: So you just insert the floating point to that position and cast it to float type.

Comment: @loser  I'm very green at sql.  Can you please show me the sql code?  Thanks.

Comment: varchar prices in trading system?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   CAST(LEFT(CLOSE_PRICE,10)
   +'.'
   +RIGHT(CLOSE_PRICE,LEN(CLOSE_PRICE)-10) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM [testTable]
```

It would be fine. I tested the result is 19.90

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this.

```
SELECT
'CLOSE PRICE'   = CAST(round(CLOSEPRICE,2)as decimal (30,2))
FROM TABLE
```

This is what I ended up using in my query.